# Как войти в mysql

Tags: mysql, cmd

Я новичок с базами данных и не очень могу понять, почему
ввод `mysql -u root -p` с последующим вводом пароля делает все спокойно, и я начинаю работать в системе mysql

а когда ввожу mysql -u root --password = 'password'
Выводится приветствие

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.21 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
```

а потом список команд, и я все еще остаюсь работать в командной строке

то есть тут c:\path>>> , а в первом случае mysql>>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас пробел до и после знака `=`. Спецификация говорит следующее:

> If you use a --password or -p option and specify a password value, there must be **no space** between --password= or -p and the password following it.

Comment: мдаа, если такая мелочь меня смутила,что же будет тогда дальше?